# \Minipage not working and how to use it effectively?

Tags: minipage, multicolumn, multicol, pagestyle

Creating a question paper, just need some ideas on how can I make the hint of **Question 2** appear parallelly under the question something like split into exact half [Img. attached for ref.], not every question's hint has two columns [Example: Question 1], each question's hint is unique.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow,multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Stack Exchange Questions}
\author{karthi }
\date{March 2022}

\begin{document}


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%                        QUESTION ID
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\questionID}[2]{
    \vspace{2.5mm}
    \begin{center}
\begin{raggedright}
\textbf{\underline{{Question: #1}}}\hfill\textit{Mark: #2}\\
\end{raggedright}
    \end{center}}



%-----------------------------------------------------------
%                        HINT
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{
    \vspace{2.5mm}
    \begin{raggedright}
    \textbf{Hint:}\\
    #1\\
    \end{raggedright}
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.15}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%                                   QUESTION NUMBER :  [1]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                  TAGS
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%start-of-the-question
\questionID{1}{}%#

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                  QUESTION
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\question
{
What is the area of this rectangle ?

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw   (46,58) -- (203.8,58) -- (203.8,129) -- (46,129) -- cycle ;
\draw (106,139) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {13 cm};
\draw (105,34) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {13 cm};
\draw (213,83) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {2 cm};
\draw (6,84) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {2 cm};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%#

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                  HINT
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------

\hints{{
\begin{align*}
 \text{Length of the rectangle}  &= \rule{146}{0.5}\\
 \text{Breadth of the rectangle}  &= \rule{146}{0.5}\\
 \text{Area of the rectangle}  &= \rule{50}{0.5}\hspace{5mm} \text{x} \hspace{5mm} \rule{50}{0.5}\\
  &= \rule{50}{0.5}\hspace{5mm} \text{x} \hspace{5mm} \rule{50}{0.5}\\
  \text{Area of the rectangle}  &= \rule{146}{0.5} \hspace{1mm} cm^{2} \\
\end{align*}
}}%# 

%end-of-the-question
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%                                   QUESTION NUMBER :  [2]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                  TAGS
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%start-of-the-question
\questionID{2}{}%#

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                  QUESTION
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\question
{Which of the following rectangle has an area equivalent to usepackage sq. m.
\smallskip

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw   (100,122) -- (233.8,122) -- (233.8,191) -- (100,191) -- cycle ;
\draw   (324,120) -- (457.8,120) -- (457.8,189) -- (324,189) -- cycle ;
\draw (50,152) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {12 cm};

\draw (141,198) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {24 cm};

\draw (275,148) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {14 cm};

\draw (383,198) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {20 cm};

\draw (68,100) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {i.};

\draw (296,99) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {ii.};


\end{tikzpicture}


}%#

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                  HINT
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------


\hints{
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
{i. 
\begin{align*}
 \text{Length of the rectangle}  &= \rule{146}{0.5}\\
 \text{Breadth of the rectangle}  &= \rule{146}{0.5}\\
 \text{Area of the rectangle}  &= \rule{50}{0.5}\hspace{5mm} \text{x} \hspace{5mm} \rule{50}{0.5}\\
  &= \rule{50}{0.5}\hspace{5mm} \text{x} \hspace{5mm} \rule{50}{0.5}\\
  \text{Area of the rectangle}  &= \rule{146}{0.5} \hspace{1mm} (=/\neq) \text{ 170 sq. m} \\
\end{align*}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
{ii. 
\begin{align*}
 \text{Length of the rectangle}  &= \rule{146}{0.5}\\
 \text{Breadth of the rectangle}  &= \rule{146}{0.5}\\
 \text{Area of the rectangle}  &= \rule{50}{0.5}\hspace{5mm} \text{x} \hspace{5mm} \rule{50}{0.5}\\
  &= \rule{50}{0.5}\hspace{5mm} \text{x} \hspace{5mm} \rule{50}{0.5}\\
  \text{Area of the rectangle}  &= \rule{146}{0.5} \hspace{1mm} (=/\neq) \text{ 170 sq. m} \\
\end{align*}}
\end{minipage}

}%# 



%end-of-the-question
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

[image: hint split]

**Note:**
I'm new to LaTeX and i'm planning to create more questions in latex, if you can suggest me any better layout for my current design is much appreciated, happy to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax of `minipage` is

`\begin{minipage}[justification]{width}` and closes with `\end{minipage}`.

Justification options are `c` for horizontally centered, `t` for top (horizontally aligned) and `b` for the bottom (horizontally aligned).

In the width you can write directly a measure in centimeters or inches; even with `\textwidth`.

For example, for a minipage, vertically centered with a 5 cm width, you must type
`\begin{minipage}[c]{5cm}` and closes with `\end{minipage}`.

If you want to use the `\textwidth` option you can type `\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}` and close it with `\end{minipage}`.

Happy TeXting.